# Url Rewrite With Python Paste

Tags: python, proxy, apache2, pylons, paste

I'm hosting a Pylons application using Apache as a proxy to paste, which serves my app. I'm trying to set up a Rewrite Rule to force browsers to update modified css, js, and image files, as inspired by the latter half of section 10.8 in [Chapter 10: Survive the Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library). It works by writing a view helper to automatically include the modification time of any of these files in the url, so the html may look like this:

```
<link href="/css/main.1302802028.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then, you use Rewrite Rules to get the server to forward the request to the location of the actual file at `/css/main.css`. That way, anytime you update your file the client's browser thinks it's getting a new file, thus ignoring its cache.

I tried setting it up in my site's conf file within apache with a rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)(css|img|js)/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png)$ $1$2/$3.$5 [L]
```

However, the Rewrites don't seem to function since I'm using Apache with `ProxyPass`. Is there either a way to get them to work with a proxy, or use paste/pylons to achieve the same effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are running on top of Linux or not, but have you simply tried setting up a symlink?

Comment: I could do that, or simply move the file, but then I'd have to change the codez or add symlinks every time I update a file. What I'm going for is something completely hands off, that updates my uris to cached resources automatically whenever I change them.